# loop for deleting the duplicates in many trials R

Tags: r, loops, duplicates

I have a data set (called **eyeData**) that in a very short version looks like this:

```
sNumber runningTrialNo  wordTar                             
1       1               vital       
1       1               raccoon                             
1       1               vital                               
1       1               accumulates                             
1       2               tornado                             
1       2               destroys                                
1       2               tornado                             
1       2               destroys                                
1       2               property                                
4       51              denounces                               
4       51              brings                              
4       51              illegible                               
4       51              frequently                              
4       51              brings                          
4       61              cerebrum
4       61              vital
4       61              knowledge
4       61              vital
4       61              cerebrum
```

I wrote a loop to delete all duplicates (same words) of the **wordTar** column for each trial separately, so the data would look like this:

```
   sNumber  runningTrialNo  wordTar                             
1           1               vital       
1           1               raccoon                         
1           1               accumulates                             
1           2               tornado                             
1           2               destroys                                
1           2               property                                
4           51              denounces                               
4           51              brings                              
4           51              illegible                               
4           51              frequently                  
4           61              cerebrum
4           61              vital
4           61              knowledge
4           61              cerebrum
```

Here's the code:

```
for (sno in eyeData$sNumber) {
for(trial in eyeData$runningTrialNo) {
ss <- subset(eyeData, sNumber == sno & runningTrialNo == trial)
ss.s <- ss[!duplicated(ss$wordTar), ]
 }
}
```

However, it runs for a very long time so I shut it down... since I am new to R environment my guess is that I am doing smth wrong with a loop. Is there a way to improve my loop, so it would give me a desirable output?

Answer (score 1):

For loops are in general slow in R. You normally want to [vectorize your code](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html). There are a ton of ways to do it, here is an example using the library `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
eyeData %>% group_by(runningTrialNo) %>%
            distinct(wordTar)
```

This is much, much faster, we can see by using `microbenchmark`, where we run the code 100 times and see how long it takes:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(dplyr = eyeData %>% group_by(runningTrialNo) %>%
                   distinct(wordTar), 
               old = for (sno in eyeData$sNumber) {
                       for(trial in eyeData$runningTrialNo) {
                           ss <- subset(eyeData, sNumber == sno & runningTrialNo == trial)
                           ss.s <- ss[!duplicated(ss$wordTar), ]
                       }
                   })

Unit: milliseconds
  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
 dplyr   1.256438   1.287158   1.567518   1.495092   1.550579  12.29212   100
   old 102.203029 110.265423 112.664063 111.789698 113.166710 304.58312   100
```

Comment: 102 min for a loop ... that's a lot, indeed. what does %>%  refer to in your code? pasting my code?

Comment: it's milliseconds, so 102 is not too bad, as long as your data isn't much larger. The `%>%` is the chain operator from `magrittr` which `dplyr` uses.  It works by passing the previous output as the first argument to the next function - try reading the [dplyr vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html]) for more details